# How to silently install using dpkg

Tags: package-management, software-installation, scripts

I have a deb package which I want to deliver via sript.
Normally when this deb file is iniated it completes with an 'OK' screen where the user must press enter.

As I want to automate the installation, I need a way to disable the display of additional information such as this, or to automatically provide what is necessary when the screen is provided.

Any help is well appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at `debconf-set-selections`?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to help:

http://www.microhowto.info/howto/perform_an_unattended_installation_of_a_debian_package.html#idp20080

or this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure debconf -f noninteractive -p critical
```

from https://serverfault.com/questions/197495/ubuntu-dpkg-non-interactive-installation